# jQuery templating doubt:

Tags: jquery, template-engine, jquery-templates

With reference to jQuery templating, Rick Strahl has an excellent writeup explaining with functionality [over here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/807874.aspx). During the course of explanation he goes on to say that jQuery supports templating in a way

> The template is merged against an
>   array in this example. When the result
>   is an array the template is
>   automatically applied to each each
>   array item. If you pass a single data
>   item – like say a stock quote – the
>   template works exactly the same way
>   but is applied only once. Templates
>   also have access to a $data item which
>   provides the current data item and
>   information about the tempalte that is
>   currently executing. This makes it
>   possible to keep context within the
>   context of the template itself and
>   also to pass context from a parent
>   template to a child template which is
>   very powerful.

I didn’t quite understand what this means. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: i just read about jquery template and its great. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

its similar asp:Repeater in asp.net. Throw array of data into it, the control populate itself based on each item in array. In this case, it just using jquery + jQuery Data Link.

so instead of use

```
for(looping)
 $("body").append("<div>"+sometext+"</div>");
```

change to

```
<script id="stockTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
<div>${objName}</div>
</script>
...and
$("#somediv").link(someJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

He's talking about nesting templates; Allowing one template to be used inside another template.  He then goes on to explain how the context for the parent template can be passed to these child templates nested inside it.

Templates need variables passed to them in order to display dynamic information.  These variables being passed, usually in an array or hash/dictionary, are often referred to as a "context". As Rick's article mentions, you're able to have a main context in your parent template, but also pass context to the child template.